# make a login system for site visitors

Tags: login, user-registration

down vote favorite
share [fb] share [tw]

I want to make a content driven site, where people can register for an account, and then have the ability to submit content/articles that they write to the website. When someone registers that person should get an email for activation, they should not be able to do anything on the site until they verify their email address.

The site admin should be able to specify what "Categories" the site has for the articles, the people who register should not. They should be able to pick from the list of categories ... just one. The should also be able to specify up to 4 tags.

Each person should have a profile page that shows their picture and all their info (except password), and links to all the articles they have submitted.

I tried searching over google, i found plugins like theme my login or users meta. But these doesn't solve my problem. Can you please suggest me, whether i have to custom code or i can get this functionality through some plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign roles to wordpress users (Contributor, Author, etc) and I'm pretty sure wordpress sends a "confirm user" email.

If you want a whole different backend or user system that would be integrated in the theme, that's no longer related to wordpress.

Comment: I dont want users to be able to able to access backend. All this system, i need on front end. I want a registration and login system on front end and profile page should also be on front end.

Comment: I have edited my question to explain in a better way, what i want to do.